# Session creation causes error with Rails engine generated under Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

There are Rails 4.1 and 3.2.12 installed on our system (Windows). When generating Rails engine with:

```
rails plugin new engine --T --mountable --dummy-path=spec/dummy
```

The engine is generated with Rails 4 by default. Under spec/dummy/config, we notice that it is:

```
Rails.application.configure do
```

Instead of in Rails 3.2.12 engine:

```
Dummy::Application.configure do
```

It seems that the Dummy is replaced with Rails in Rails 4 engine. Then we changed the gemspec to `rails, '~> 3.2.11'` and `bundle install` and replaced `Rails.application` with `Dummy::Application` in `dummy/config` (now it is rails 3.2.12 in gemfile.lock). However there is error when creating sessions under spec/dummy:

```
rake db:sessions:create
```

The error is `undefined 'configure'` or `undefined 'migration_error='` even after replacing `Rails.application` with `Dummy::Application`. There is not much info about what's new in Rails 4 engine. How to fix this problem?